# Save requests.get() response locally for use in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I'm building a Python script to scrape some data (World Cup scores) from a url using Requests and BeautifulSoup4 and while I'm testing my code I'm making more requests than the website would like, resulting in this error periodically:

```
 requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: Max retries exceeded with url
```

I don't actually need to keep calling the page, surely I only need to call it once and save the returned data locally and feed it into beautiful soup. Surely I'm not the first to do this, is there another way? This is probably trivial but I'm pretty new to this- thanks.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-cup/2018/06/26/world-cup-2018-fixtures-complete-schedule-match-results-far/"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Write it to a file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the HTML in a file once:

```
response = requests.get(url)
with open('cache.html', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Then, next time, simply load it from the file:

```
with open('cache.html', 'rb') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to wait 1 or 2 sec if the error appear:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-cup/2018/06/26/world-cup-2018-fixtures-complete-schedule-match-results-far/"
try:
     response = requests.get(url)
     html = response.content
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
except:
    print("Connection refused by the server..")
    print("Let me sleep for 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Continue...")
    continue
```

I couldn't test it, so maybe it will not work like this.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to the question but I do appreciate the alternate method, potentially will use this in future for dynamic pages